# Trying to center an image via CSS

Tags: html, css, image, center, margin

I'm trying to center this image by place it really center of the page but it always seems to be more towards the left.

What part am I missing or which part should I cut out? Thanks

Here's my Code:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="thumbnail"><img src="tilden regional park.jpg" /></div>
    <div id="heading">Tilden Regional Park</div>
</body>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
    body {
      font-family:  Open Sans, Arial, Verdana;
      margin: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #container {
      width:960px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      padding: 30px 0px;
    }

    #thumbnail {
      height: 500px;
      width: 500px;
    }

    #thumbnail img {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Why you dont use it as background image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="thumbnail"><img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" /></div>
    <div id="heading">Tilden Regional Park</div>
</div>
```

The only required styles are:

```
#thumbnail {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#thumbnail img {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

You need to add `auto` margins to the element you want centred, this will be `#thumbnail` not the image itself, because the image has 100% width and height.

http://jsfiddle.net/F3337/

Answer (score 0):

Remove margins from #container and add `margin: 0 auto` to #thumbnail. There's also no need for the margin statement on the body.

Debugging is easier by assigning colours to the divs.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add "margin: 0 auto" to the id thumbnail, not the img ! so :

```
#thumbnail {
   height: 500px;
   width: 500px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#thumbnail img {
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Is your answer different from mine?

Comment: Sorry you were faster :)